# rails: how to not include some db attributes in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

My DB table has a column that can contain a very big amount of data.
I do not want this data to be part of the corresponding rails object (model).

How do I tell in the model that I do not want to store this field in memory  ?

Initially this comes from the fact that I have a session bigger than 4k and rails raises a ActionController::Session::CookieStore::CookieOverflow exception.

Thanks for your help,
Mickael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to specify the columns explicitly via the find-option `:select`.
However, storing models in the session is discouraged. How about storing just the object-id in the session, and holding the Model-Object itself in `Rails.cache`?

Comment: To be clearer - storing in the session is dangerous for your data validity - models in the session are not updated when data changes in the database unless you do it manually so you will end up with all kinds of weirdness

Comment: If you want a bit more about why it is a bad idea from a security point of view look here:  http://www.rorsecurity.info/the-book/

Answer (score 1):

When loading your model you could explicitly set the columns you want to select and skip large columns:

```
MyModel.find(id, :select => 'column1, column2, column3')
```